# plaintext output from pcap in tshark (with options from wireshark?)

Tags: linux, shell, wireshark, tshark

I'm trying to run a script which will allow me to export all my pcap files into plaintext versions like with wireshark.

My issue is that I need to have **packet summary line**, **packet details expanded**, **packet bytes**, and **each packet on new page** under the packet format options. I believe packet summary line is on by default, packet details are "as displayed" using -V flag.

[This](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tshark) is the man page I've been using.

I have used the command:

```
tshark -V -r "$file" >> TEXT_out.txt;
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to have **packet summary line**, **packet details expanded**, **packet bytes**

`tshark -PVx -r "$file" >>TEXT_out.txt`, at least with newer versions of TShark.

> and **each packet on new page**

Not supported in TShark, unfortunately.

Comment: To add a form feed for each packet you could do: `tshark -PVx -r "$FILE" | perl -pane 's/^(Frame \d+)/^L\1/' >> TEXT_out.txt`